# Import .rpt and .cs file of Crystal report to generate report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I can import the .rpt and .cs file of crystal report via OpenFileDialog, but i dont know how i can use that to generate report. is it possible to do that just importing the .rpt and .cs and you can use the imported file to generate report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to Crystal reports SDK (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine)
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Then open the report

```
using (ReportDocument rep = new ReportDocument())
{
     //Open report
     rep.Load("SomeReport.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);

     //rep.PrintOptions = ...
     rep.PrintToPrinter(1 /*NumCopies*/, true, 1, 9999);

     //or
     rep.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "SomeReport.pdf");
}
```

This assumes that the report knows where to get its data from. Manually providing data requries additional steps.